# Unable to print a list in html using ngFor

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angular and front end. I am trying to call a rest Api to fetch a product list. And then I am trying to print them in the html page.

**product.component.html**

```
<div class="page-title">Product List</div>
<div class="bgblue">
    <div class="product-preview-container">
        <ul *ngIf="!emptyProductList">
            <p>Available Products</p>
            <li *ngFor="let product of products">
            <p>Product Name  : {{ product.productName }}</p>
            <p>Product Code  : {{ product.productCode }}</p>
            <p>Product Price : {{ product.productPrice }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul *ngIf="emptyProductList">
            <p>No Product Found  </p>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**product.component.ts**

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMessage = '';
  emptyProductList = true;
  products: Product[];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    this.products = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Called ngOnInit method');
    this.productService.fetchProductList().subscribe(
      (productList: Product[]) => {
        this.products = productList; 
        if(this.products.length>0){
          this.emptyProductList = false;
          console.log('not empty');
        }       
      }, err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error;
      })
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

**product.service.ts**

```
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: ProductAdapter) { }

  fetchProductList(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get(PRODUCT_LIST_API, httpOptions).pipe(
      map((data: any[]) => [data].map((item) => this.adapter.adapt(item)))
    );
  }
  
}
```

**product.model.ts**

```
export class Product {
    constructor(
      public id: number,
      public productCode: string,
      public productName: string,
      public productPrice: number
    ) {}
  }

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
  })
  export class ProductAdapter implements Adapter<Product> {
    adapt(item: any): Product {
      return new Product(item.id, item.productCode, item.productName, item.productPrice);
    }
  }
```

Updating the `productList` values :

```
[Product]
0: Product
    id: undefined
    productCode: undefined
    productName: undefined
    productPrice: undefined
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

Response json in Postman:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "productCode": "P01",
        "productName": "Pencil",
        "productPrice": 10.0
    }
],
```

**Output :**

```
Product List

Available Products
Product Name :
Product Code :
Product Price :
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Pleas show the value of `products`

Comment: try this `consoole.log(this.products)` in `fetchProductList`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi getting element values as undefined in the console log. I have added my service class and how I am mapping the items. Please check once.

Comment: Show `productList` values

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Added the `productList` values. please check.

Comment: Try initialisation of the Products's array. `products: Product[] = []`.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi thats what i was doing in constructor. But I have checked as u said. Its still the same.

Comment: Try to write `data.map` instead of `[data].map` in the service

Comment: Why `[data].map`? data is already array so there is no need to `[]` use `data.map`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `[data].map((item) => this.adapter.adapt(item)))`. Note that `data` is already array, so there is no need to `[]`.

Try this one:

```
data.map((item) => this.adapter.adapt(item)))
```

Comment: Nope its still there. The problem is during mapping : `return this.http.get(PRODUCT_LIST_API, httpOptions).pipe( map((data: any[]) => data.map((item) => this.adapter.adapt(item)))
    );`

Comment: If I do only `return this.http.get<Product[]>(PRODUCT_LIST_API, httpOptions);` I have the entire ResponseObject data with headers and body  .. but I need to extract the body from there

Comment: Use `this.http.get(PRODUCT_LIST_API, httpOptions).then()`

Comment: Getting this warning : `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<Product[]>'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235130/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-som).

Comment: Use this one: `this.productService.fetchProductList().subscribe(
            (productList: Product[]) => {
                this.products = productList.map(item => this.adapter.adapt(item));
                if (this.products.length > 0) {
                    this.emptyProductList = false;
                    console.log('not empty');
                }
            })`

Comment: resolved the issue. i was returning a ResponseEntity object instead of the List, so the mapping was not working. It is working now.

Comment: Your solution did not resolve the issue. I made a mistake in returning the object from my rest api. I was returning a ResponseEntity object instead of a List, so the mapping was not working. It is working now.

Comment: But thanks anyways for you spending time on this issue. I am grateful. Appreciate a lot.